# Lognormal and radial

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, modeling, lognormal-distribution

Is lognormal distribution a class of radial distribution? P.S Gaussian, truncated Gaussian are all classes of radial distribution.

Definition of radial distribution:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_distribution_function

Comment: Please define the term "radial distribution", in your question. If you quote a definition, please give a proper reference.

Comment: It would be better to include the definition *in your question*, rather than merely  pointing to it.

Answer (score 0):

If we take that definition of radial distribution function to mean that the density function only depends on distance from origin, the lognormal distribution is clearly not radial, since density for negative arguments is zero.